# Fiddler web debugging: Missing time information?

Tags: performance, fiddler

Normally its possible to display a fiddler session on a timeline, to see the sequence of the web requests and how long it took to get a response.

However, for some reason a certain session does not contain any time information, therefore the timeline feature does not work.
The Statistics of the requests show blank time values:

```
ACTUAL PERFORMANCE
--------------
ClientConnected:    00:00:00:0000
ClientDoneRequest:  00:00:00:0000
Gateway Determination:  0ms
DNS Lookup:         0ms
TCP/IP Connect:     0ms
ServerConnected:    00:00:00:0000
ServerGotRequest:   00:00:00:0000
ServerBeginResponse:    00:00:00:0000
ServerDoneResponse: 00:00:00:0000
ClientBeginResponse:    00:00:00:0000
ClientDoneResponse: 00:00:00:0000
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

This is a recorded fiddler session (.saz file) I got from a customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that your customer is using a seriously outdated version of Fiddler to collect the logs, one that predated the addition of the timing information.

You can check for sure by looking at the raw bytes of the file in a hex editor; at the very bottom of the SAZ file, you will see text like so:

"Fiddler (v2.2.1.2) Session Archive. See http://www.fiddler2.com"

Alternatively, just have the customer upgrade to the very latest Fiddler version.